# WooCommerce: Create script for (http) cronjob

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do I create a script in WooCommerce which can progress orders and is callable by a (http) cronjob from outside?

Example: myshop.com/myscript should be called by a cronjob. The script itself should be able to execute the following:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();
```

This code is possible in my theme's functions.php. But how do I include the "WooCommerce Core" (?) in a "normal" php script or where do I have to create a new script, that the Core is available and the script is callable from outside?

Answer (score 0):

Now my solution looks like this:

1. creating a shortcode in my functions.php like this

   ```
   function handle_orders()  {
      // handle my orders and write debug info in $r
      return $r;
   }

   add_shortcode('handle_orders', 'handle_orders');
   ```
2. including my [handle_orders] shortcode in a new page and give it a url like '/cronjob-handle-orders'
3. letting the (http) cronjob call my created url

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I found myself in the same situation later today, here is what I did :

in the functions.php of your theme

```php
if (isset($_GET['my_cron_call'])){
    include_once 'inc/cron.php';
    add_action('init','my_cron',11);
}
```

in a sub directory ./inc/ put your file cron.php and wrote a my_cron function as the entry point.

```php
function my_cron(){
    //do here whatever you want in a wordpress / woocommerce context
    //$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
}
```

you can then call your wp url with your cron :

```
curl https://your-wordpress.org/?my_cron_call
```